# Cassandra/Spark Read Performance

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

We have a workflow where we read data from Cassandra and push the data to oracle using Spark(JDBC). 
I have a problem where all  data for a particular day was going into one Cassandra Partition. I used to read the data from the single partition and then do a spark repartition to achieve parallelism. So while reading all the data from the table using Spark we used to get a write performance to oracle of 4Million/hour.

To solve this, i split the data into smaller partitions using counter based Cassandra buckets. Even then with smaller partitions, and no more repartition we are still getting around 3Million/hour performance.

Can you guys help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem not on the Oracle side?

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure. Oracle side its fast. After bucketing the data, how do you suggest reading it in spark. One partition at a time and push it to Oracle or read multiple at once and push

Comment: The performance is extremely slow if execute the query.
   Without executing the query its extremely fast.
   
   rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
        //Getting the connection from the pool
        val conn = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection
        conn.setAutoCommit(false)
        val stmt = conn.createStatement()
        
        partitionOfRecords.foreach { row =>
val query = create INSERT/UPDATE queries for reach row based on the data
stmt.addBatch(query)
counter = counter + 1
if (counter > 5000) {
stmt.executeBatch()
counter = 0
 }conn.commit()}}

Comment: I would say, personally, that you have too big batches... Per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#insertedID1, "For both standard update batching and Oracle update batching, Oracle recommends you to keep the batch sizes in the general range of 50 to 100. This is because though the drivers support larger batches, they in turn result in a large memory footprint with no corresponding increase in performance. Very large batches usually result in a **decline in performance compared** to smaller batches."

Comment: Trying batch size 50. No Change. I should be doing something wrong